# How to align major and minor tick labels exactly next to each other with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, vertical-alignment, axis-labels, xticks

I have a graph with major tick labels the first day of months, and minor tick labels the other days of the month. If you look closely you can see that the day strings are not aligned. I would like to move minor labels a little bit down to align them with majors. or vice versa.

*I don't want to make minor ticks bigger, or majors smaller*

**How would I do that?**

This is the code piece, to generate the major/minor labels like in figure:

```
# draw canvas for x-ticks/labels
fig.canvas.draw()

# x-axis ticks/labels
x_minor_labels = [item for item in ax.xaxis.get_minorticklabels()]
for item in x_minor_labels:
    if int(item.get_text()) in (8, 15, 22, 29):
        item.set_visible(True)
    else:
        item.set_visible(False)

x_major_labels = [item for item in ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels()]
x_major_labels[0].set_text(x_major_labels[0].get_text() + str(2021))
ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks().tolist())
ax.set_xticklabels(x_major_labels)
```

---

```
>>>x_minor_labels[0].get_position()
(18629.0, 0)
>>>x_major_labels[0].get_position()
(18628.0, 0)
```

[image]

**Expected Outcome:**

[image]

Comment: They are just offset by the tick label envy difference, so you can just pad by that amount.  It should be fixed.  

Btw have you tried concise date formatter?

Comment: @JodyKlymak do you know the default major minor tick lengths in pixels? I pad the difference and apperently its `pad=5`. However I don't know if its 5pixels or some other unit... See below my answer

Comment: I don’t know off the top of my head, but it’s easy to look up.  Note that pad is in points, not pixels.   One point =1/72 of an inch, and is the same unit as font sizes.  Tick length is also in points, so figuring the pad should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I can move minor labels via:

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='minor', pad=5)
```

However, I am not sure setting `pad=5` makes minor labels exactly next to major labels for all plots (for my case it works). Probably also depends on the figure size etc... So an eleganter solution should exist.

[image]

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! It was a little tedious to find the correct padding (8.1), but once I had calibrated properly, I could produce multiple figures, as they all shared common properties. `plt.gca().xaxis.set_tick_params(which="minor", pad=8.1)`

Comment: It's worth experimenting with padding the major axis instead. I settled for `plt.gca().xaxis.set_tick_params(which="major", pad=3.4)` to get everything aligned, but a little closer to the axis than with the previous padding.

Answer (score 0):

Labels are just text objects, so you can just set a new position with the `set_position` method.

```
major_labels = ax.xaxis.get_majorxticklabels()
_, y = major_labels[0].get_position()

for label in ax.xaxis.get_minorxticklabels():
     x, _ = label.get_position()
     label.set_position(x, y)

fig.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: sadly major and minor labels y-coordinate is 0. So setting both of them to 0 does not change anything. Be aware I don't want to change their x-coordinate. I just want to move minor labels a little bit down, so that they will align with major labels

Comment: You are right. Weird. I will leave the answer up as a warning to others.